# R bulk column renaming

Tags: r, dplyr

I used read_excel() to import a spreadsheet then use clean_names(). The columns are named x1, x2, x3, ... x23. I want to rename them ward_1, ward_2, etc. I can type them out manually using the rename() function.

```
data %>% rename(ward_1 = x1, ward_2 = x2)
```

Instead typing in every replacement, how would do you quickly rename them all?

Comment: `rename_with(data, ~gsub("^x", "ward_", .))`

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution:

```r
library(tidyverse)

data <- data.frame(x1=1:2, x2=7:8, x24=2:3)

data %>% 
 rename_with(~ str_c("ward_", str_extract(.x, "\\d+$")))

#>   ward_1 ward_2 ward_24
#> 1      1      7       2
#> 2      2      8       3
```